# Printing value of tensorflow variable inside object

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to print the value of a Tensorflow variable that is defined inside an object. To better illustrate my issue, I am currently trying to run the monodepth library. It has 2 main files, [dataloader](https://github.com/mrharicot/monodepth/blob/master/monodepth_dataloader.py) and [main](https://github.com/mrharicot/monodepth/blob/master/monodepth_main.py). Basically dataloader iterates over a text file of

```
class MonodepthDataloader(object):
    """monodepth dataloader"""

    def __init__(self, data_path, filenames_file, params, dataset, mode):
        self.data_path = data_path
        self.params = params
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.mode = mode

        self.left_image_batch  = None
        self.right_image_batch = None

        input_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filenames_file], shuffle=False)
        line_reader = tf.TextLineReader()
        _, line = line_reader.read(input_queue)

        split_line = tf.string_split([line]).values

        ...
        left_image_path  = tf.string_join([self.data_path, split_line[0]])
        left_image_o  = self.read_image(left_image_path)
```

I am trying to print out `left_image_path` to verify that it is being generated correctly. However this is in an object being called by monodepth_main. That is monodepth_main calls the dataloader with the following lines:

```
dataloader = MonodepthDataloader(args.data_path, args.filenames_file, params, args.dataset, args.mode)
left  = dataloader.left_image_batch
```

As a result I can't just use sess.run(x). I have also tried using tf.Print(line, [line]) but nothing shows up.

How do I print out the value of a tensorflow variable inside an object? Specifically `left_image_path`?

Comment: Is there an error while running `sess.run(dataloader.left_image_batch)`?

Comment: I added the lines `temp = sess.run(dataloader.left_image_batch)
        , print(temp)` after `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())` in `monodepth_main`. There is no error but the program just hangs and processes something. My guess is it's calling dataloader per each of 4000 images

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/mdscui/monodepth-clone/tree/master/source . I have minimized and changed the monodepth library to use only 1 image to debug. I am looking to print out 'left_image_path' because it doesn't train on windows tensorflow but does on bash which leads me to think that the path is wrong when joined.